# References in Rust

Tags: rust

I try to understand the borrow mechanism and references in Rust, and for this reason I created the following small example:

```
extern crate core;

use core::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Element(pub (crate) [u8; 5]);

impl Debug for Element {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut ::core::fmt::Formatter) -> ::core::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Element({:?})", &self.0[..])
    }
}

impl Element {
    fn one() -> Element {
        Element([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    }
    fn double(&self) -> Element {
        let mut result = *self;
        for i in 0..5 { result.0[i] = 2*result.0[i]; }
        result
    }
    fn mut_double(&mut self) -> Element {
      for i in 0..5 { self.0[i] = 2*self.0[i]; }
      *self
    }
}

fn main() {
  let mut a = Element::one();
  println!("a = {:?}", a); // a = Element([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
  a = a.double();
  println!("a = {:?}", a); // a = Element([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
  a = (&a).double();
  println!("a = {:?}", a); // a = Element([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
  a = a.mut_double();
  println!("a = {:?}", a); // a = Element([8, 8, 8, 8, 8])
  a = (&mut a).mut_double();
  println!("a = {:?}", a); // a = Element([16, 16, 16, 16, 16])
}
```

So, the above code works, but my confusion comes when calling the `double` method. As you can see it is defined as `fn double(&self) -> Element`, so it basically takes an immutable reference. Now in the main, I create a new `Element` variable called `a`, and then call `double` method on it twice. First time I just do `a.double()`, second time `(&a).double()`. Both of them seem to work correctly, but I do not understand why the first call `a.double()` is a valid and compiler doesn't complain about it. Since `a` is of type `Element`, not of type `&Element`, and clearly the `double` method asks for `&Element`, so about a reference. Same thing also happens with the `mut_double` method. Why do I not have to specify `(&a)` or `(&mut a)` when calling the `double` and `mut_double` methods, respectively? What is happening under the hood with Rust?

Comment: I believe this is part of the type coercion (specifically auto-referencing) [behaviour of the dot operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/dot-operator.html). A more detailed explanation is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules/28552082#28552082).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short: the language works like that because it's a lot more convenient.

Long ([extract from the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#wheres-the---operator), **emphasis** is mine):

> #### Where’s the `->` Operator?
>
> In languages like C++, two different operators are used for calling methods:
>   you use `.` if you’re calling a method on the object directly and `->` if
>   you’re calling the method on a pointer to the object and need to dereference
>   the pointer first. In other words, if `object` is a pointer,
>   `object->something()` is similar to `(*object).something()`.
>
> Rust doesn’t have an equivalent to the `->` operator; instead, Rust has a
>   feature called *automatic referencing and dereferencing*. Calling methods is
>   one of the few places in Rust that has this behavior.
>
> Here’s how it works: when you call a method with `object.something()`, **Rust
>   automatically adds in `&`, `&mut`, or `*` so `object` matches the signature of
>   the method.** In other words, the following are the same:
>
> ```
> p1.distance(&p2);
> (&p1).distance(&p2);
> ```
>
> The first one looks much cleaner. This automatic referencing behavior works
>   because methods have a clear receiver—the type of `self`. Given the receiver
>   and name of a method, Rust can figure out definitively whether the method is
>   reading (`&self`), mutating (`&mut self`), or consuming (`self`). The fact that
>   Rust makes borrowing implicit for method receivers is a big part of making
>   ownership ergonomic in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer.